# How to get actual image from image path in http response?

Tags: reactjs, http, axios, httpresponse, response-headers

I am making a http request which responds back with an image path like so

```
{
    poster-path: /heb234gdb.jpg
}
```

I tried adding this path to the end of the same http request, removing everything else and using this path at the end of the main api url, simply using this path and a lot more but I can't get the image to show. What is the way to do this?

P.S.: I did not give the api urls purposely but if any more info is needed please comment

Comment: It depends entirely on the api. You will need to read the documentation and see if it provides any information. An example of how it is dependant on an API is the following:

Let's use google.com as an example this response could be coming from. The image URL could be google.com/heb234gdb.jpg or google.com/images/heb234gdb.jpg it depends entirely on the API. Normally its the first case but i have seen my fair share of the API's that do something similar to the second even though you're not meant to.

Comment: Thank you. I will go through the api and try to find it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , Edit your question!.
You can have the description in Code Snippet ,its annoying.

Comment: He hasn't put the description in a code snippet, he put an example object of what the network request responds with. It seems perfectly fine to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Like @jessy said I had to read the documentation and I found a completely separate API's link at the end of which I had to add the path to get the image.